# Magento Admin grid problem

Tags: magento-1.7, module, admin, database, grid

I have a magento admin grid module and when I am inside the grid on the admin menu it shows me the header and the add item button but it throws this **error**

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method NAMESPACE_Garantiaextendida_Model_Mysql4_Garantiaextendida_Collection::setPageSize() in G:\xampp\htdocs\webpage\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php on line 553**

This is my mysql4 model collection

```
   <?php 

class Felisiakluciano_Garantiaextendida_Model_Mysql4_Garantiaextendida_Collection extends  Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('garantiaextendida/garantiaextendida');
    }   
}
```

Can somebody help me? Please its more than urgent. Thanks and Good Bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if NAMESPACE_Garantiaextendida_Model_Mysql4_Garantiaextendida_Collection is extending the right core Magento abstract collection class that it is supposed to.

Comment: Many Thanks, that was the problem, i was extending the wrong class. Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract instead of Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract , again thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The collection you are calling is the cause. That is why you are having an error when calling setPageSize(). This can be caused by several things, here are a few to check: not declared model in config.xml, error in files inside Model, error when calling the collection with an incorrect name.

You can get a fully functional admin/backend extension from [here](http://www.webspeaks.in/2010/08/create-your-first-adminbackend-module.html) and try to reuse it as a base.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, i will use that example as guide.